# How to detect if it is the user's first visit on Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, cookies, drupal-6

I'm using the [splash module](http://drupal.org/project/splash), but I'm not getting the results I want. I'd to show a lightbox presentation for when the user first logs in. I'm probably going to write a custom template that prints to a block, and then dynamically display the block based on a certain condition.

I'm working with cookies, and here is some calls I'm working with:

```
 if (!$cookie_data['time']) {
      print $block;
 } else { }
```

Very basic, but I just basically want to write a condition that checks if it's the user's first visit.

> *UPDATE: Okay. This was my mistake, I need it to be able to do it only for Anonymous users. My bad. Here is the code I'm using, but it isn't working sufficiently...

```
 function custommodule_init() {

      setcookie('splash_status',$splash_status,time()+3600*24*365);

      if (!isset($_COOKIE['splash_status'])) $_COOKIE['splash_status'] = 0;

      $splash_status = $_COOKIE['splash_status'] + 1;

      if ($splash_status > 1) {
              drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sbasplash') . '/sbasplash.js');
              drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'sbasplash') . '/sbasplash.css');

              // Action to enable block

      } else {

              // Action to disable block

      }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure this question's title correctly reflects what you're talking about (i.e is it "first login" or "first visit"?).

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module, implement "hook_user" and insert your code in the "insert" operation. When a user gets inserted into the database for the first time, your code will be executed. You can use it to add a your block or set a session variable and display your block according to its value.

```
yourcustommodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch($op){
    case 'insert':
       //your code here
       //example: $_SESSION['show_block'] = 1; and then unset after block is shown
    break;     
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey correct me if wrong , but isnt this insert case when a user registers , that s when actual record goes in database , but this wont get invoked when logging in

Comment: Yes, i made a correction above, I need it to work when an Anonymous user looks at the content (front page) for the first time. It works well with my authenticated users though...

Answer (score 0):

By default I think there s no drupal api to detect first login , we need a custom code , perhaps a new column attribute set to status = 1 , in hook_user for login check if status = 1 if status is 1 then display splash page and make status 0 so that next time no splash page comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your custom module is set to run after the splash module.  You can set the `weight` value in the `system` table of your module to above that of the splash, making sure the cookie is always set before your code checks for it.